# C++ Loops not starting with 0

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

So, I've been trying to create a simple program that just needs an empty array and a size, and fills it with numbers from 1 to the specified number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* fill(int empty[], int size) {
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        empty[i] = i;
    }
    return empty;
}

int main() {
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    int* empty = new int[size];
    fill(empty, size); 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << empty[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So, thats my code.
It works perfectly fine when int i, in the fill() method is 0, but I want to start the numbers from 1, and when I do, it looks like this:

```
-842150451
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
```

Notice how it replaces 0 with a weird negative number? This is when I enter '30' as my array size.

When i set the value of i to 0, it just replaces that negative with 0.
Is there any way to just start the array at one?

Thanks.

Comment: `empty[0]` is just uninitialized.

Comment: `for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {`

Comment: If you're starting from 1 when filling the array, you should also start from 1 when printing it.

Comment: The first index of an array in c/c++ is always 0. You cannot change that. It's better to start arrays from 0 anyway.

Comment: I will not downvote this question.  When you use index based array, you should be careful. Consider if you can use another data structure.

Comment: Well you fill the elements 1 through 29... then print the elements 0 through 29... so what were you expecting element 0 to hold?

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a way to start the loop at 1. (i know that it will work if I just increment the array up by one).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the number in the array starting keep the loop starting from 0 (because arrays in C++ are zero based) and simply set the values to `i + 1` instead than simply `i`:

```
int* fill(int empty[], int size) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        empty[i] = i + 1;
    }
   return empty;
}
```

Comment: From the question: **It works perfectly fine when int i, in the fill() method is 0, but I want to start the numbers from 1**. How is your response a solution?

Comment: The OP wants to start the number in the array from 1 - the array is zero based (as usual) - so the solution is simply to set the elements to `i+1`

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see that. You should update the answer to explain what you're doing and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are filling the array starting from index 1, but then outputting it starting from index 0.  What do you expect?

> Is there any way to just start the array at one?

Yes.  If you need `size` elements and for whatever reason need them to start at index 1, then you allocate one *extra* element:

```
int* empty = new int[size + 1];
```

Now you ignore element 0 in all subsequent operations*.  And you also iterate up to *and including* `size`:

```
for (i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    empty[i] = i;
}
```

- I would, however, still initialize it to *something*.

I would warn you that if you're only doing this because you have an irrational fear of zero, then you should *get over that fear* and write code that other C++ programmers can understand.  Starting arrays at 1 without good reason is sloppy and will annoy the heck out of anyone who reads your code.

If this is only a matter of you wanting the *numbers* beginning at 1, but the array index zero-based, that's a different matter.  Just add 1 when you fill.

Note that there is already a function in the standard library for this.  It's in `<numeric>` and is called `std::iota`:

```
std::iota( empty, empty + size, 1 );
```

Comment: I think it's the numbers filling the array he wants to start from `1` not the array indexes.

Comment: Yeah I realised that and edited my answer.  I could take the array-indexing stuff out, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
int* fill(int empty[], int size) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        empty[i] = i + 1; // one more than the index
    }
    return empty;
}
```

You need to set the value to *one more* than the array index. So the *array index* counts from `0 - size - 1` while the *value* (`i + 1`) counts from `1 - size`.

Answer (score -2):

You should know that the subscript of an array starts from `0` and to `size - 1`. For example:

```
int a[10];  // The subscript is from a[0] to a[9]
```

If you want to have an array whose size is `sz` and subscript starts from `1`, you can do

```
constexpr int sz = 10;
int a[sz + 1];
```

then, just use the subscript range from `1` to `sz` and ignore `0`.